# React - How does this 'SetInterval' work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, following their tutorial. They made a clock component which updates itself, and has these functions:

```
tick () {
    this.setState({
        date: new Date()
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
        () => this.tick(),
        1000
    );
}
```

They called `setInterval` with an anonymous (arrow) function, that only calls `tick`.

**My Question:**
Why does the above work, while placing `this.tick` like I did below doesn't?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
        this.tick,
        1000
    );
}
```

Comment: Because with the code at the end of your question, `this` won't refer to the component when `tick` is called. `setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)` would work, though. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: Or you can bind the context of `tick` to the component, e.g in your constructor: `this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);` then you can use `this.tick` like the later case.

Comment: setInterval maps a different 'this' if the passed function is not an arrow function. That's one of the new features introduced with arrow functions.